# React Custom Hook with Context and Typescript: Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Option'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-context

I am working on a React app that contains a Custom Hook that is available via Context. The app uses Typescript and defines custom types like Option, which is an object that represents the sate of a Radio element or a Checkbox.

Broadly speaking these are the steps that the code follows:

- Creates context on top of the component tree that contains a custom state hook
- The custom hook contains a custom Typescript type (Option)
- Down the tree, a component reads the custom state hook to render Radios or Checkboxes

First it defines the Custom Hook with Context to make it available to the rest of the components. It also includes the custom Option type:

```js
import React from "react";

// Custom Option type
export type Option = {
    name: string;
    enabled: boolean;
    checked: boolean;
};

const FiltersContext = React.createContext<Option[] | null>(null);

function useFilters() {
    const context = React.useContext(FiltersContext);
    if (!context) {
        throw new Error(`useFilters must be used within a FiltersProvider`);
    }
    const [filters, setFilters] = context;

    return {
        filters,
        setFilters
    };
}

function FiltersProvider(props: any) {
    // Prepare default options array
    const options: Option[] = [
        {
            name: "Option 1",
            enabled: true,
            checked: true
        },
        {
            name: "Option 2",
            enabled: true,
            checked: false
        }
    ];

    // Assigns default options
    const [filters, setFilters] = React.useState<Option[]>(options);
    const value = React.useMemo(() => [filters, setFilters], [filters]);

    return <FiltersContext.Provider value={value} {...props} />;
}

export { FiltersProvider, useFilters };
```

Later on and down the tree, I have a component that reads the state of that custom hook. The problem comes here:

```js
import * as React from "react";
import { Option, useFilters } from "../../context/use-filters";

const Options: React.FC = () => {
    const { filters } = useFilters();

    return (
        <Wrapper>
            {filters.map((option: Option, key: number) => (
                <OptionWrapper key={key}>
                    <RadioButton defaultChecked={false} name={option.name} disabled={false} onClick={() => {}} />
                    <Label>{option.name}</Label>
                </OptionWrapper>
            ))}
        </Wrapper>
    );
};

export default Options;
```

The code gets `filters` from `useFilters` and then `map` through them to create `RadioButton` components. Typescript complains saying:

```
Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Option'
```

So, as far as I understand `filters` is detected as an `Option` type and not as an array of Options.

If I loop through `filters` before `return`, the options appear on the console, but Typescript still complains with that error:

```
filters.map((option: Option) => console.log(option.name));
```

I am sure I am misunderstanding something very essential so I beg you pardon in advance, but if you could shed some light into it I would be hugely grateful!

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your context type is wrong, it should be something like this:

```
const FiltersContext = React.createContext<[Option[], Dispatch<SetStateAction<Option[]>>] | null>(null);
```

Your context would mean that you only return filters as your context value, but you return also the setFilters function so you need to account for that too. Typings for setFilter come from:

```
import { Dispatch, SetStateAction } from 'react';
```